# sql query to Combine different fields from 2 different tables with no relations except a common field - SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2

Tags: sql, join, database-design, sql-server-ce, union

My first question here. This has been a really helpful platform so far. I am some what a newbie in sql. But I have a freelance project in hand which I should release this month.(reporting application with no database writes)

To the point now: I have been provided with data (excel sheets with rows spanning up to 135000). Requirement is to implement a standalone application. I decided to use sql server compact 3.5 sp2 and C#. Due to time pressure(I thought it made sense too), I created tables based on each xls module, with fields of each tables matching the names of the headers in the xls, so that it can be easily imported via CSV import using SDF viewer or sql server compact toolbox added in visual studio. (so no further table normalizations done due to this reason).

I have a UI design for a typical form1 in which inputs from controls in it are to be checked in an sql query spanning 2 or 3 tables. (eg: I have groupbox1 with checkboxes (names matching field1,field2.. of table1) and groupbox2 with checkboxes matching field3, field4 of table2). also date controls based on which a common 'DateTimeField' is checked in each of the tables.

There are no foreign keys defined on tables for linking(did not arise the need to, since the data are different for each). The only commmon field is a 'DateTimeField'(same name) which exists in each table. (basically readings on a datetime stamp from locations. field1, field 2 etc are locations. For a particular datetime there may or may not be readings from table 1 or table2)

How will I accomplish an sql select query(using Union/joins/nested selects - if sql compact 3.5 supports it) to return fields from the 2 tables based on datetime(where clause). For a given date time there can be even empty values for fields in table 2. I have done a lot of research on this and tried as well. but not yet a good solution probably also due to my bad experience. apologies!
I would really appreciate any of your help! Can provide a sample of the data how it looks if you need it. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Sample Data (simple as that)

### Table 1

t1Id     xDateTime           loc1  loc2  loc3

(could not format the tabular schmema here. sorry. but this is self explanatory)
... and so on up to 135000 records existing imported from xls

### Table 2

t2Id     xDateTime           loc4  loc5  loc6

.. and so on up to 100000 records imported from xls. merging table 1 and table 2 will result in a huge amount of blank rows/values for a date time.. hence leaving it as it is.
But a UI multiselect(loc1,loc2,loc4,loc5 from both t1 and t2) event from winform needs to combine the result from both tables based on a datetime.
... and so on

---

I managed to write it which comes very close. I say very close cause i have test in detail with different combination of inputs.. Thanks to No'am for the hint. Will mark as answer if everything goes well.

```
SELECT T1.xDateTime, T1.loc2, T2.loc4 FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.xDateTime = T2.xDateTime
WHERE (T1.xDateTime BETWEEN 'somevalue1' AND 'somevalue2')
UNION
SELECT T2.xDateTime, T1.loc2, T2.loc4 FROM Table1 T1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.xDateTime = T2.xDateTime
WHERE (T1.xDateTime BETWEEN 'somevalue1' AND 'somevalue2')
UNION
SELECT T1.xDateTime, T1.loc2, T2.loc4 FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.xDateTime = T2.xDateTime
WHERE (T1.xDateTime BETWEEN 'somevalue1' AND 'somevalue2')
```

Comment: Sample data always helps. SQL Fiddle is a great way to show the data and it makes it much easier for folk to give you solutions that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @kbbucks.
Works with this so far.

```
SELECT T1.MonitorDateTime, T1.loc2, T.loc4 
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.MonitorDateTime = T1.MonitorDateTime 
WHERE T1.MonitorDateTime BETWEEN '04/05/2011 15:10:00' AND '04/05/2011 16:00:00' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT T2.MonitorDateTime, '', T2.loc4 
FROM Table2 T2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.MonitorDateTime = T2.MonitorDateTime 
WHERE T1.MonitorDateTime IS NULL AND T2.MonitorDateTime BETWEEN '04/05/2011 15:10:00' AND  '04/05/2011 16:00:00'
```

Comment: any one? any ideas how this can be extended with a third table?

Answer (score 0):

If 't1DateTime' and 't2DateTime' are the common fields, then apparently you need a query such as

```
SELECT table1.t1DateTime, table1.tiID, table1.loc2, table2.t2id, table2.loc4
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.t2DateTime = table1.t1DateTime
```

This will give you values from rows which match in both tables, according to DateTime. If there is also supposed to be a match with the locations then you will have to add the desired condition to the 'ON' statement.

Comment: hi No'am, Thanks.The problem is when I use a WHERE clause to return the values in between a datetime range. In this case only those records are returned for which values exists for the date range, in BOTH the fields(table1.loc2, table2.loc4). In my case for a given date range BETWEEN t1 and t4, table1(loc2) and table2(loc4) has records at t1. But table1(loc2) does not have values for t2,t3,t4. Instead table2(loc4) has values at theses times. Here only loc2,loc4 values are reurned for t1. FULL OUTER JOIN not supported. UNION ALL shows the combined values into a single column. any work around?

Comment: hi No'am. With your sql as a starting point combined with the article in http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm  I managed to work it around. See edit with code in my main comment. So far so good. will mark as answer after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> For a given date time there can be even empty values for fields in table 2

my understanding would be that you are not interested in orphaned records in table 2 (based on date) so in that case a LEFT JOIN would do it:

```
SELECT table1.t1DateTime, table1.tiID, table1.loc2, table2.t2id, table2.loc4
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.t2DateTime = table1.t1DateTime
```

However if there are also entries in table2 with no matching dates in table1 that you need to return you could try this:

```
SELECT table1.t1DateTime, table1.tiID, table1.loc2, ISNULL(table2.t2id, 0), ISNULL(table2.loc4, 0.0)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.t2DateTime = table1.t1DateTime
WHERE (T1.t1DateTime BETWEEN 'somevalue1' AND 'somevalue2')
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.t2DateTime, '0', '0.0', table2.t2id, table2.loc4
FROM table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 on table1.t1DateTime=table2.t2DateTime
WHERE table1.t1Datetime IS NULL AND T2.t2DateTime BETWEEN 'somevalue1' AND 'somevalue2'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66735/discussion-on-answer-by-kbbucks-sql-query-to-combine-different-fields-from-2-dif).